# How to define a valuation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, valuation-theory

We say a ring $R$ is a DVR if is a local integral domain and the maximal ideal is principal. I want to show that this ring admits a discrete valuation $\nu: K(R) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \cup\{0\}$ that satisfies:

$1)$ $ \nu(a+b) \geq \min\{\nu(a),\nu(b)\}$

$2)$ $\nu(ab) = \nu(a)+ \nu(b)$

$3)$ $\nu(a)=\infty \Leftrightarrow a=0$

$4)$ $ R = \{x \in K(R) : \nu(x)\geq 0\}$

My idea is that: I need to define $\nu(x)=0$ for every unit which are the elements that are not in the maximal ideal. And $a$ is the generator of the maximal ideal we should define $\nu(a)=1$.
I would like to define $\nu(x)$ as the exponent of $a$ in the factorization of $x$. However, this works only if $R$ is a UFD.
I would appreciate any help to generalize this idea to the case without assuming UFD.

Comment: Every DVR is a PID, and every PID is a UFD.

Comment: I think you need to add $R$ noetherian to say that is a PID

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring So you are asking if a local ID whose maximal ideal is principal is a PID then. Which is a different question.

Comment: Actually, now I don't know what you are asking. Is $K(R)$ the Grothendieck group? The field of fractions?

Comment: $K(R)$ is the field of fractions of the ring $R$. I got that definition from some lecture notes but there should be a mistake as the definition of the valuation implies that the ring is a PID.

Comment: Yes. Condition 2 from the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1):

What you try to show is false without Noetherian condition. See e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155621/condition-for-a-local-ring-whose-maximal-ideal-is-principal-to-be-noetherian

Define $\mu(a) = \sup \{n\in\mathbb N: x^n \mid a\}$ where $(x)$ is the maximal ideal of $R$. The hard part is to show (3), i.e. if $\mu(a)=\infty$ then $a=0$, which is the same as to say $I = \cap_{n=0}^\infty\mathfrak   m^n=\{0\}$. Note that $\mathfrak m I=I$, if $R$ is assumed to be Noetherian then by Nakayama's lemma, $I=\{0\}$.

(1) is straightforward, (2) can be deduced from (3).

From here, it's easy to show that any nonzero element in $R$ can be uniquely decomposed as $x^nu$ where $u$ is a unit. So a DVR is a UFD, but it's not so easy to show this directly.